# Classic ASP: Type mismatch: 'GroupCheck'

Tags: asp-classic, active-directory

I have a function named GroupCheck, which is designed to get the logged in users group from AD. It is, however, giving me the following error:

```
Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a000d' 
Type mismatch: 'GroupCheck' 

/ldap.asp, line 67
```

Line 67 is where I call the function, passing in the Request.ServerVariables("AUTH_USER")

The following function is stored in a file which is included at the top of the page:

```vb
 <%
 function GroupCheck(user)
      dim user, ADUser, objCom, objCon, objRS, membership
      ADUser = "LDAP://OU=Staff,OU=Users,DC=example,DC=internal"
     ' Make AD connection and run query'
      Set objCon = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
      objCon.provider ="ADsDSOObject"
      objCon.Properties("User ID") = "EXAMPLE\user"
      objCon.Properties("Password") = "Test"
      objCon.Properties("Encrypt Password") = TRUE
      objCon.open "Active Directory Provider"
      Set objCom = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
      Set objCom.ActiveConnection = objCon
      objCom.CommandText = "SELECT memberOf FROM '" + ADUser + "' where  sAMAccountName='*" + 'user + "*' AND UserAccountControl <> 514"
     Set objRS = objCom.Execute
     Do While Not objRS.EOF Or objRS.BOF
          if isNull(objRS.Fields("memberOf").value) then    
               membership = ""
          else
               for each item in objRS.Fields("memberOf").value
                    membership = item + "<br>"
               next
          end if
          if inStr(membership, "UserGroup") then
               GroupCheck = 1 
          else
               GroupCheck = 0 
          end if
          objRS.MoveNext
          Response.Flush
     Loop
     'Clean up'
     objRS.Close
     objCon.Close
     Set objRS = Nothing
     Set objCon = Nothing
     Set objCom = Nothing
end function
%>
```

I really don't know what the problem is, because /ldap.asp, line 67 is :

```vb
    Set getMembership(username)
```

EDIT: My code for ldap.asp is:

```vb
    getMembership = GroupCheck(Request.ServerVariables("AUTH_USER"))
'This should fetch all the accounts that appears in the "Contact Centre" group
    if getMembership = 1 then
    'Response.Write "<td><a href='entry.asp?account_name=" & objRS("sAMAccountName") & "'>Edit</a></td>"
elseif objRS("sAMAccountName") = session("username") then
Response.Write "<td><a href='entry.asp?account_name=" & objRs("sAMAccountName") + "'>Edit</a></td>" 
else Response.Write "<td></td>"
end if
    Response.Write "</tr>" + vbCrL
    objRS.MoveNext
    Response.Flush
Loop
Response.Write "</table>"
' Clean up
objRS.Close
objCon.Close
Set objRS = Nothing
Set objCon = Nothing
Set objCom = Nothing
%>
```

Comment: i have noted that you wrote  ´´sAMAccountName='*" + 'user + "*' AND´´ is this correct ?

Comment: Please show the relevant code from ldap.asp, i.e. the line where you include the file that contains the function, and the line(s) where you call the function. Also, what's with the `+` used for concatenation? AFAIK, that doesn't work in VBScript; use `&` instead.

Comment: Martha you should file an Answer about the "+" in place of "&"... a very likely culprit here.

Comment: You have `function GroupCheck(user)` then `dim user` - not sure what the impact of declaring user when it is already a function parameter. I would remove user from the DIM statement.

Comment: My code for ldap.asp is:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what exactly is in line 67?

```
Set getMembership(username)
```

or

```
[unknown variable] = GroupCheck(Request.ServerVariables("AUTH_USER"))
```

?

In any case, this is probably the cause of the problem:

```
objCom.CommandText = "SELECT memberOf FROM '" + ADUser + "' where  sAMAccountName='*" + 'user + "*' AND UserAccountControl <> 514"
```

In VBScript, the `+` operator is for arithmetic addition. `"SELECT memberOf From '"` cannot be converted into a number; hence the type mismatch. Probably. (I can't be sure because I don't know how you're calling or including the function.)

Instead, use the proper VBScript concatenation operator, `&`.

```
objCom.CommandText = "SELECT memberOf FROM '" & ADUser & "' where sAMAccountName='*" & user & "*' AND UserAccountControl <> 514"
```

Also, you're potentially shooting yourself in the foot by dimming a variable with the same name as the function argument:

```
 function GroupCheck(user)
     dim user, ADUser, objCom, objCon, objRS, membership
        '^^^^
```

It may still work if you do that, but it's just not a good idea.

Comment: To be clear, `+` _can_ be used for string concatenation, but only if both arguments are strings ([reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kd1e4aey%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)). It is much more reliable to use `&`.

Comment: @CheranShunmugavel: I did not know that. Learn something new every day, I guess. :) (Of course, it's still a very bad idea to use `+` for concatenation.)